# Column Options in TFS 2012

Tags: c#

I am trying to get this window in TFS 2012 through C#. [image]

Does anyone has any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the class:

```
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Controls.ColumnsPickerControl
```

Which is in:

```
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Controls.dll
```

I've not played much with it, but you need to pass it a `WorkItemStore` and probably some other parameters to get it how you want.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried this and all that I get is the control but empty. I have read the documentation in the MSDN and look for an example but there isn't any. Do you have something that could help me maybe?